# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<capture#2-of ? super T> to Comparator<? super T>

Tags: java, generics

```
public class MergeSort<T> {
     private  Comparator<? super T> c;

      <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
            mergeSort(a, 0, a.length);
            this.c = c;
        }
}
```

Getting compilation error at `this.c = c`. Error is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator to Comparator"

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense -- where is the mergeSort method?

Comment: What if you get rid of the `<T>` before the `void` statement in your method? It seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<T>` on the `sort` method is shadowing the one in `MergeSort<T>`, so they don't coincide, they're two independent types that happen to be both  refered to as `T`. Just remove it and it will work:

```
 void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {

        this.c = c;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the user does

```
MergeSort<Integer> sorter = new MergeSort<>();
String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b"};
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String> { ... };

sorter.<String> sort(array, comparator);
```

Then in `this.c = c` left-hand side has type `Comparator<Integer>` and the right-hand side is a `Comparator<String>`. This clearly doesn't make sense, and this your code shouldn't compile.